# Import a video in a chroma key mask in a video

Tags: compositing-nodes, masking

I try to put a video in a "chroma key" mask in another video. How can I make the size of the video as big as the mask? It is always full sized like the normal video. (Pong shall be in the monitor in the middle :)

Regards,
Michael

[image]

Comment: See also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23865/is-it-possible-to-take-a-mask-clip-and-connect-it-to-a-specific-point-on-a-mov/23902#23902

Comment: With a plane track there is no need to use green.

Comment: [This](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57008/2217) is another method that may help you.

Comment: If you're still at a loss after reading the links @Mike I use a method so simple it's child's play.  I'd put it up as an answer here but I'll just get my knuckles rapt - 'cos it's not what you asked in that I don't use the VSE (or Movie) editor, or Chroma Key for this effect.  It does do exactly what you're trying to achieve though and I'm sure many others are doing it my way also.  If you ask the question without the ref'ce to the VSE, I'd be game to answer it.  :)

Comment: So, after I tried out the linked answers (Thank you for these), im asking again. :-) The problem is, at a later time in the video, there are moving objects in front of the monitor. It is not possible to see them anymore. The next problem is, the inserted video is shaking out of the tracking rectangle (black monitor in the middle of the figure). @Edgel3D I do not understand what you say I have to do to get the child´s play solution :-)

Comment: I haven't actually mentioned how I've done this for the reason given above.  By far the most accurate way of placing a 'substitute video inside another is Blender's Video Tracking. This is particularly so when the camera is moving fast to one side, rotating or is hand held.  Because of your plight I've done a small video with 'manual tracking using both Keyframes and Shapekeys.  Considering   , but I've found jobs often don't need that sort of time spent on them. when not opting for the Camera Tracking feature.

Comment: Overlay jobs can avoid using Blender's Camera-Tracking feature when it's not worth the time anticipated.
You simply drag the plane's corners onto the in-video monitor and texture it with another video or image and as often as 
necessary, employing Keyframes, Shape keys, and a few simple rules.  Violent movement may even conceal minor KF/SK errors.
On reading your plight I've done a Blend file and video to demonstrate manual tracking with a fast orbiting camera from a previously produced movie. (close to 70 degrees odd)   Blender hasn't tracked it yet. It will but time is my problem.

Comment: further: to the previous... The overlay video is UV mapped and when transformed with Keyframes and shapekeys, the image automatically distorts to suit the plane's newly assumed shape and viewed angle.  No compositor, no tracking, no Chroma-key and virtually unlimited bkd video-cam viewing angles.   Rendering in OpenGL is a WYSIWYG scenario, very fast and works well with this method.

Comment: Not sure what happened 3 comments up.  It was supposed to have been discarded when posted, and in favour of the last two.  It's stuck there now. (sigh)