# Why won't my mask display a full image?

Tags: compositing-nodes, image, video, masking, movie-clip-editor

I am trying to impose an image on a video, I made the mask and the alpha over with the video, image and mask, but it shows up like this:

[image: compositor nodes and result]

Also, How can I get a mask to display multiple images, like a slideshow?

Comment: Please keep your questions to one question at a time. However to get a slideshow type of effect: First create your slideshow then, just use an animated image sequence or video (the slideshow) as the input for the Plane Track Deform Node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is not working like you expected is because you are using a mask. Right now all you are getting is a black and white mask that has no transformational information so all it is doing is "hiding" the part of the image outside of your mask.

What you want to do is use a Plane track and a [Plane Track Deform Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/distort/plane_track_deform.html). After setting up the plane track, that node will deform whatever image you give it as an input to match the skew of the plane track.

1. Switch to the *Tracking* mode in the *Movie Clip Editor*, add 4 tracking markers.
2. With the 4 markers selected go to the *Solve* tab in the *Tool Shelf* and click the *Create Plane Track* button.
3. Drag the corner points of the newly created plane track to match your frame.
4. Now in the compositor set up your nodes to look something like this:
   [image: compositor nodes]
   The Plane Track Deform Node is the heart of this, that is where all the data from the actual plane track gets in to the compositor to distort the image.

---

[My answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57008/2217) show the whole process of setting up the track and the needed nodes in more detail.