# transform (distort) image in the VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transforms, image

Is there a way to free-transform (distort) an image in the VSE. But not in a perspective way but by moving the corner pins?

Comment: Do it in the 3D view by assigning it to a plane as texture and deforming said plane object.

Comment: Is [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57002/2217) what you are trying to do?

Comment: As pointed out by @David, you can do that in the compositor. https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/compositing/types/distort/corner_pin.html and https://vimeo.com/25516157