# VSE: can you modify strips trapezoidally (skew)?

Tags: transforms, image, video-sequence-editor

I know I can modify strips in scale, position, and rotation. however, I want to modify an image strip to overlay a projector slide from a video, but to make the aspect ratio look like the scene, I need to make the right corners closer together than the left corners:

As you can see below, the overlayed image is square but the projected image behind needs a small amount of trapezoidal skew to keep the perspective the same.

There is no 3d Blender, this is all VSE with existing video footage and a higher resolution original slide because the projected one was washed out in the camera footage.

**Can Blender provide a trapezoidal skew, if so, how?**

[image: Presentation slide]

Comment: simple answer: VSE in vanilla Blender cannot do this AFAIK. But it is pretty easy to just setup a new scene for that. For the background, just add an image as plane and use your background video footage. Then add another image as plane and move and rotate that as you need it. Use your projector footage for that and add a camera and render it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform a strip in the vse in a non-uniform way?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57002/how-to-transform-a-strip-in-the-vse-in-a-non-uniform-way) and [transform (distort) image in the VSE](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76794/) But the short answer is: no, you cannot do that in the VSE.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, I accepted the suggestion, thanks for that.   However, in our case we skewed the image externally using a netpbm pipeline, mostly with `pamhomography`: `for i in *.png; do echo === $i;  pngtopam -alphapam < $i | pamhomography --to "964,1628 2996,1700 3016,2920 976,2980"  |pamscale -xysize 512 338 | pamcomp -mixtransparency -xoff=244 -yoff=407 - 1920x1080-alpha.pam| pamtopng > scaled-$i ; done`

Comment: @KJ7NLL I'm sorry, I have no idea what these hieroglyphics mean :D But your question was if you can do this in the VSE somehow, so I'm not sure what you want to tell me with this external skewing...